# Восстановление системы с контрольной точки Windows 2003

Tags: windows, настройка

Вопрос. Есть в Windows 2003 возможность восстановления системы с последней контрольной точки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, такая возможность есть.

Comment: А как ей воспользоватся? А то, я что-то ее не нахожу (простите за ошибки клава бывает западает).

Comment: Не помню :-) Помню, что а) эта ф-ция есть. По идее где-то через панель управления можно восстановиться. А настраивается стандартно - через свойства системы, но обычно создание контрольных точек я отключаю - толку от них реально никакого. б) есть опция "Последняя работоспособная конфигурация" в бут-меню операционной системы. Вызывается оно по F8 в процессе загрузки.

Comment: спасибо,толку нет это точно но руководитель думает что он очень умный,говорит сделай сделай с контрольной точки восстановление,у него дома видишь ли помогло,ну я сделал толку ноль только время потратили(

Comment: Руководителя нужно слушать, не нужно ему откровенно перечить :-) Просто сразу предупреждаете - это не поможет, а потом стиснув зубы делаете, после чего предъявляете результат :-)
"у него дома видишь ли помогло" - бывает, что восстановление из контрольной точки помогает.

Comment: В XP Пуск->Все->Стандартные->Служебные->ВосстановлениеСистемы.